# mvc3 simple custom output caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I'm trying to follow some tutorial where on one place I should override GetVaryByCustomString .... 
Code is following

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
        {
            // It seems this executes multiple times and early, so we need to extract language again from cookie.
            if (arg == "culture") // culture name (e.g. "en-US") is what should vary caching
            {
                string cultureName = null;
                // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
                HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
                if (cultureCookie != null)
                    cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
                else
                    cultureName = Request.UserLanguages[0]; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

                // Validate culture name
                cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

                return cultureName.ToLower();// use culture name as cache key, "es", "en-us", "es-cl", etc.
            }

            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
        }
```

Question is: Where I should put these code, in which class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override it in **Global.asax**